# @distributed seems to work, function return is wonky

Tags: julia, distributed

I'm just learning how to do parallel computing in Julia. I'm using `@sync @distributed` at the start of a 3x nested `for` loop to parallelize things (see code at bottom). From the line `println(errCmp[row, col])` I can watch all the elements of the array `errCmp` be printed out. E.g.

```
From worker 3:    2.351134946074191e9
From worker 4:    2.3500830193505473e9
From worker 5:    2.3502416529551845e9
From worker 2:    2.3509105625656652e9
From worker 3:    2.3508352842971106e9
From worker 4:    2.3497049296121807e9
From worker 5:    2.35048428351797e9
From worker 2:    2.350742582031195e9
From worker 3:    2.350616273660934e9
From worker 4:    2.349709546599313e9
```

However, when the function returns, `errCmp` is the array of zeros I pre-allocate at the begging.

Am I missing some closing term to collect everything?

```
function optimizeDragCalc(df::DataFrame)
    paramGrid = [cd*AoM for cd = range(1e-3, stop = 0.01, length = 50), AoM = range(2e-4, stop = 0.0015, length = 50)]
    errCmp    = zeros(size(paramGrid))
    # totalSize = size(paramGrid, 1) * size(paramGrid, 2) * size(df.time, 1)
    @sync @distributed for row = 1:size(paramGrid, 1)
        for col = 1:size(paramGrid, 2)
            # Run the propagation here
            BC = 1/paramGrid[row, col]
            slns, _ = propWholeTraj(df, BC)
            for time = 1:size(df.time, 1)
                errDF = propError(slns[time], df, time)
                errCmp[row, col] += sum(errDF.totalErr)
            end # time
            # println("row: ", row, " of ",size(paramGrid, 1),"   col: ", col, " of ", size(paramGrid, 2))
            println(errCmp[row, col])
        end # col
    end # row
    # plot(heatmap(z = errCmp))
    return errCmp, paramGrid
end
errCmp, paramGrid = @time optimizeDragCalc(df)
```

Comment: Each process gets its own separate copy of `errCmp`.  Maybe try a [`SharedArray`](https://docs.julialang.org/en/v1.0.0/manual/parallel-computing/)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You did not provide a minimal working example but I guess it might be hard. So here is mine MWE. Let us assume that we want to use `Distributed` to calculate sums of `Array`'s columns:

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using StatsBase
data = rand(1000,2000)
res = zeros(2000)
@sync @distributed for col = 1:size(data)[2]
    res[col] = StatsBase.mean(data[:,col])
    # does not work!
    # ... because data is created locally and never returned!
end
```

In order to correct the above code you need to provide an aggregator function (I keep the example intentionally simplified - a further optimization is possible).

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2)
@everywhere using Distributed,StatsBase
data = rand(1000,2000)    
@everywhere function t2(d1,d2)
    append!(d1,d2)
    d1
end
res = @sync @distributed (t2) for col = 1:size(data)[2]
    [(myid(),col, StatsBase.mean(data[:,col]))]
end
```

Now let us see the output. We can see that some of the values have been calculated on worker `2` while others on worker `3`:

```
julia> res
2000-element Array{Tuple{Int64,Int64,Float64},1}:
 (2, 1, 0.49703681326230276)
 (2, 2, 0.5035341367791002)
 (2, 3, 0.5050607022354537)
 ⋮
 (3, 1998, 0.4975699181976122)
 (3, 1999, 0.5009498778934444)
 (3, 2000, 0.499671315490524)
```

Further possible improvements/modifications:

- use `@spawnat` to generate values at remote processes (instead of the master process and sending them)
- use `SharedArray` - this allows to automatically distribute data among workers. From my experience requires very careful programming.
- use `ParallelDataTransfer.jl` to send data among workers. Very easy to use, not efficient for huge number of messages.
- always consider Julia threading mechanism (in some scenarios it makes life easier - again depends on the problem)

Comment: If only this had been on the documentation page! I understand it so much better now! Thanks for making your own working example, I really appreciate it