# julia @distributed doesn't scale up

Tags: parallel-processing, julia

I'm trying to learn to use parallel computing in julia and I'm trying to execute this code (found [here][1])

```
using Distributed
addprocs(2, exeflags="--project=.")
@everywhere begin
    using Distributed
    using StatsBase
    using BenchmarkTools
end
data = rand(1000,2000)    
@everywhere function t2(d1,d2)
    append!(d1,d2)
    d1
end
@btime begin 
    res =  @distributed (t2) for col = 1:size(data)[2]
        [(myid(),col, StatsBase.mean(data[:,col]))]
    end
end
```

The result is in my laptop with 4 cores and 8 threads (2.21 GHz) is

```
11.836 ms (182 allocations: 78.06 KiB)
```

But when I try to scale up, adding 2 more core, the timing doesn't seem to improve:

```
addprocs(2, exeflags="--project=.")
nworkers() # result 4
@everywhere begin
    using Distributed
    using StatsBase
    using BenchmarkTools
end
data = rand(1000,2000)    
@everywhere function t2(d1,d2)
    append!(d1,d2)
    d1
end
@btime begin 
    res =  @distributed (t2) for col = 1:size(data)[2]
        [(myid(),col, StatsBase.mean(data[:,col]))]
    end
end
```

The final computing time is:

```
15.449 ms (340 allocations: 132.34 KiB)
```

Do you have some idea of what I'm doing wrong?
Thank you
[1]: [@distributed seems to work, function return is wonky](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52432639/distributed-seems-to-work-function-return-is-wonky)

Comment: There is no free lunch. all those milliseconds are consumed for communication between processes and sending data here and there. Try with code that actually does a significant >1s computations

Comment: Or use threads instead of processes, they are much "cheaper" to make as memory doesn't need to be copied. Julia >=1.3 has excellend API for multi-thread programming..

Comment: thank you both, @Antonello can you give me a working example with threads?

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example with GroupedDataFrames:

```
using DataFrames
using CSV
function main(input_file::String, output_file::String, by_index::Array{Symbol,1})
    data = DataFrame(CSV.File(input_file))
    grouped_rows = groupby(data, by_index)

    Threads.@threads for group in collect(SubDataFrame, grouped_rows)
        index_value = group[1, by_index]
        println(index_value)

        # compute slow function for group of rows in dataframe
        output_vector = costly_function(group)
        # copy vector to elements in the dataframe
        group[:, :p] .= output_vector
    end

    CSV.write(output_file, data)
end
```